# How to set switch case through sending mail using Html in NodeJs

Tags: node.js

I want to send mail notification which one is streaming in html data . Is there a way to send mail notification in table format and only essential data in node.js?

I am getting only token expired message.

Here is my code:

```
    var sendStreamingTemplate = function (req, res) {

    authToken = req.headers.authorization;
    userAuthObj = JSON.parse(UserAuthServices.userAuthTokenValidator(authToken));
    var todayDate = new Date();
    var expireDate = new Date(userAuthObj.expire_date);
    tokenOK = TokenValidator.validateToken(userAuthObj.user_id, authToken).then(function (userSessions) {
        if (userSessions.length === 1) {
            if (expireDate >= todayDate) {
                StreamingTemplateId = req.params.id;
                StreamingTemplate.findById(StreamingTemplateId).then(function (streamingTemplate) {
                    if (streamingTemplate === null) {
                        res.status(404).json({
                            message: 'Streaming not found...'
                        })
                    } else {
                        res.status(200).json(streamingTemplate);
                       if (streamingTemplate.id === 1){
                           var streaming;
                           switch(streaming){
                               case notification_log.template_id === 1:
                               html: '<head><style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;}th, td {padding: 10px;text-align: left;}</style></head>' +
                                '<body><table style="width:100%"><tr><th>Broadcaster</th><th>Broadcasterchannel</th><th>status</th></tr>' +
                                'case:sudi <tr><td>Sudi</td><td>sudinews channel</td><td>channel is streaming</td><p>Message:Streaming sucessfully running...</p>'+
                                '}</table></body>'
                                break;
                               case notification_log.template_id === 2:
                                html: '<head><style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;}th, td {padding: 10px;text-align: left;}</style></head>' +
                                '<body><table style="width:100%"><tr><th>Broadcaster</th><th>Broadcasterchannel</th><th>status</th></tr>' +
                                'case:kasturi <tr><td>kasthuri</td><td>kasturinews channel</td><td>channel is streaming</td><p>Message:Streaming sucessfully running...</p>'+
                                '}</table></body>'
                                break;
                               case notification_log.template_id === 3:
                                html: '<head><style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;}th, td {padding: 10px;text-align: left;}</style></head>' +
                                '<body><table style="width:100%"><tr><th>Broadcaster</th><th>Broadcasterchannel</th><th>status</th></tr>' +
                                'case:TamilOli <tr><td>TamilOli</td><td>Entertainment channel</td><td>streaming</td><p>Message:Streaming sucessfully running...</p>'+
                                '}</table></body>'
                                break;

                               default:
                               break;
                           }

                       }
                    }
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    res.status(500).json({
                        message: 'something went wrong...'
                    });
                });
            } else {
                res.status(401).json({
                    message: 'Not Authorized...'
                });
            }
        } else {
            res.status(401).json({
                message: 'Token Expired...'
            });
        }
    }).catch(function (err) {
        res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Token Expired...'
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: how to send mail using this code

Comment: Bro I think you are a genius if you understand something in your code... You should refactor it extract in smaller chunks, use express middlewares for token authorization checking, do not clump all te code in one file, it is messy and very hard to understand, also use a wrapper function to catch errors, extract your big switch case in helper module, and you will find your bug in no time.

Comment: ok let's leave the code .i want to send mail in table format if response is 1 means it should send first data only.how to write code in node js